# R ggvis: sliderInput for fontSize

Tags: r, ggvis

I am struggling to make a ggvis plot where the font size of the X-axis text would be controlled by a slider. Now I am getting the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In toJSON(unclass(x), container, collapse, ..., .level = .level +  :
  converting an R function to JSON as null. To change this, define a method for toJSON() for a 'function' object.
```

Here is the code:

```
mivector<-c(1.5,2,2.5,2,2.5,3,2.5,3,3.5)
treats<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")

library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

plotdf<-data.frame(mivector,treats)

plotdf %>% ggvis() %>% layer_points(x=~treats,y=~mivector) %>% 
  add_axis("y",grid=F,title="") %>% 
  add_axis("x",grid=F,title="",properties=axis_props(labels=list(fontSize=input_slider(min=8,max=20,value=14,label="Font size of the X-axis text"))))
```

I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: `ggvis` uses `vega` to draw plots. A typical drawing has three stages: create a vega object with specific options (axis, grid etc.), data binding and finally update the plot according to the data. You can only specify the attributes (including axis labels) when a plot (and its vega object) is created. Hence the axis labels and the font sizes can't be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you can do that currently with `ggvis`.

When `ggvis` is plotting, three different types of messages is sent to your browser.

1. Plot specifications (width, height, axis ticks, labels and axis font sizes etc)
2. Plot data (points, lines, their colors, opacity etc.)
3. A `ggvis` command. Currently there is only one: `update`.

Although `ggvis` allows you to create [interactive plots](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html), it is important to keep in mind that you can only update the data in (2). ( once you update the data in (2), (3) is implied automatically ).

The plot specifications in (1), however, is packed in a **JSON object** and send your browser **only once** when the plot is initiated. You can read [this post from ggvis's author](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html) about this.

That means, all plot specifications that you want to specify must be JSON-serializable. 
Functions, can't be packed into JSON (unless, as the warning specified, define a method for `toJSON()` for a `function` object).

A slider created by `input_slider()` is a function: (more precisely, a reactive variable, which is a function itself),

```
> slider <- input_slider(min=8,max=20,value=14,label="Font size of the X-axis text")
> typeof(slider)
[1] "closure"
```

hence it can't be part of the plot specifications.

---

#### Solution

You can't solve your problem in `ggvis` alone. But you can address this issue by using [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/). You can check out this [tutorial for Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/).
Also, See [this article](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html) for how you can integrate a `ggvis` plot into a Shiny application.

In short, you will have to:

- Create a `sliderInput` in Shiny (similar to `input_slider` in `ggvis`) that is used to specify the x-axis font size. This part goes into the **ui.R** of a Shiny application.
- Create a `ggvisOutput` object in **ui.R**.
- In **server.R**, wrap your `ggvis` plotting expressions in a **reactive** environment, in which you can let the `fontSize` equal to the value from the `sliderInput`.

The trick here is to wrap your `ggvis` call in a **reactive** environment.
Therefore, every time the slider input changes, the reactive environment is re-evaluated, hence the `ggvis` function is called again, and the  **ENTIRE** plot is redrawn. 
(Remember the 1. 2. 3. stages of `ggvis`? They will all be updated because literally you make a new `ggvis` function call every time you changes your slider input).

Comment: If you want to address this with Shiny and experience problems, let me know and I'm glad to help.